# Проприетарные драйвера ATI/AMD в Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: драйвер, linux

"Драйверы устройств" выдают сообщение

> Проприетарные драйверы устройств не используются в вашей системе.
> Этот драйвер активирован но не используется.

Как заставить его использоваться?

Проприетарный драйвер FGLRX для видеокарт ATI/AMD. Пробовал удалить, и установить снова, после установки просит перезагрузки для активации, сделал, получил:

> Этот драйвер активирован, но не используется.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Что за система какие дарйвера устройств. Скорректируйте тему вопрос "Проприетарные драйвера ATI/AMD в Ubuntu" иил что-то типо того....

Comment: ....ребята...я б с удовольствием ответил на Ваши замечания, если бы...поподробнее- пытался поменять "Визуальные эффекты" в "Параметры общего вида" получил сообщение- ""не удалось включить визуальные эффекты"

Comment: какое у тебя ядро?

Comment: на pae ядрах драйвер FGLRX не работает, точнее не работает с пакета, после некоторых манипуляций у людей работает

Comment: я незнаю что за ядро (как узнать?), раньше работало...

Comment: uname -a

Comment: Linux alex-laptop 2.6.32-30-generic-pae #59-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 1 23:01:33 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

проблема в pae ядре, драйвер FGLRX не работает на нем. Поменяйте ядро.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-2.6.32-22-generic
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-2.6.32-30-generic-pae
```

От такого решения, памяти будет использоваться не 4GB, а 3,5GB.